# Why can't I use MailItem.BodyFormat without reference to Outlook library?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works fine when the VBA Project includes a reference to Microsoft Outlook Object Library. When it doesn't, the last line produces the `Invalid procedure call or argument` error.

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'error here :-(
```

I don't think I have ever encountered a situation where a property or method is available in a library only when I add a reference to that library.

This problem occures on Excel 2010/2013. I have not tested it on other versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem is simply that olFormatHTML has no value without the reference, since it's part of an Outlook enumeration. Try using the literal value instead:

```
olMail.BodyFormat = 2
```

or declare a constant first:

```
Const olFormatHTML as Long = 2
```

Comment: The Office [Dev Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/Ff869979.aspx) lists the properties without enumeration. Is there a handy reference we should know?

Comment: @EFH If you click on the `OlBodyFormat` constant link at the top of that page, it lists them.

Answer (score 1):

That's because constants aren't available without a reference.

Specifies the format of the body text of an item.

Name
 Value
 Description

olFormatHTML 
 2
 HTML format

olFormatPlain 
 1
 Plain format

olFormatRichText 
 3
 Rich text format

olFormatUnspecified 
 0
 Unspecified format

```
olMail.BodyFormat = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Other thing which helped me was as below :

```
olMail.BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
```